# Chrome store asking money for chrome extension, Where can I host it for free

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created one extension for my portfolio, but for hosting the extension in chrome store asking for money. Is there any alternative ways to host and put it in portfolio

I have tried GitHub, this is very common way to see the code
But I want to download someone and install